# error..missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed in MsFit model

Tags: r

`cbr`

```
>29.68000 24.85000 26.10000 24.53000 24.42000 22.44000 29.20000 29.36000 29.73580 
 28.47520 25.47400 15.56450 11.84480 14.44225 18.77750 22.97450 14.27825 13.47400 
 13.36025 15.90100 17.97175 15.06950 15.39325 14.01240 13.14400 10.33800 10.60080 
 11.37760  9.23940  5.99820
```

`cbrlag1`: is the 1st `lag` of `cbr`

```
>NA 29.68000 24.85000 26.10000 24.53000 24.42000 22.44000 29.20000 29.36000 
 29.73580 28.47520 25.47400 15.56450 11.84480 14.44225 18.77750 22.97450 14.27825 
 13.47400 13.36025 15.90100 17.97175 15.06950 15.39325 14.01240 13.14400 10.33800 
 10.60080 11.37760  9.23940
```

Running an MSwM

```
mod3=lm(cbr ~ cbrlag1, data=monetary)
mod3_ms = msmFit(mod3, k = 2, p = 1, sw = rep(TRUE, 4))
```

getting the error

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
>     4 nodes produced errors; first error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Thinking it is as a result of the lagged `CBR`

substituting the `NA` in `cbr` with 0 and running the equation,

```
cbrlag1[is.na(cbrlag1)]=0
```

i get the error

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
>     4 nodes produced errors; first error: dim(X) must have a positive length

when i run the equation with any other variable except the lagged `cbr` i get results

Any help on how to overcome this problem?
The available questions are not specific to this problem.

Comment: above is the dataset i am using

Comment: What is the structure of `monetary`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik it is  data.frame

Comment: just pulled cbr and cbrlag1 from the larger monetary dataframe

Comment: @egodym  could you be having some ideas as well?

Comment: @spacedman any lead?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with all the relevant code.